# Adding to NSDictionary in while loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm adding Annotations to a map, and in order to call them I need to store their Database ID value in an Dictionary

```
int i = 0;
...

while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {   

     int thisvenueid = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
     NSNumber *vid = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:thisvenueid];

      if (dict == nil) {
           dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      }
      [dict setObject:vid forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

And then I'm using it like this:

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:[dict objectForKey:selectedVenue] animated:YES];
```

However, this just crashes (Sigbart .. how I don't like Sigbart). I'm very thankful for any advise.

Comment: Is there more descriptive error output?

Comment: As you don't increment `i` in your loop, the key is always 0. Maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to select Annotation and passing `NSNumber` instead of object of `MKPlacemark`

please refer to documentation:

**selectAnnotation:animated:**
Selects the specified annotation and displays a callout view for it.

```
- (void)selectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

***Parameters***
**annotation**
The annotation object to select.
**animated**
If YES, the callout view is animated into position.
**Discussion**
If the specified annotation is not onscreen, and therefore does not have an associated annotation view, this method has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `setObject`? From what it looks like, you should be using `addObject`:

```
[dict addObject: vid forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

Forgive me if this is not the problem - haven't worked with Objective-C for some time.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary doesn't have an `addObject:forKey:` method, so that would probably be why he's using the other one.